# Unknown JS adding margin to element (can't find where the JS is)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

My site has a video for the background (html5 video element) and somehow, it's displaying half way across the page (as opposed to stretching the entire page). When inspected, the video element has:

```
element.style {width: 1349px; margin-top: -344px; margin-left: 0px; }
```

but I have no clue where this `margin-top: -344px` is coming from. I bought the website template. Could anyone offer some suggestion as to how I might find out the cause of this please?

Comment: Thanks yentup! U'll call the hosting company. I've been getting a lot of traffic the last few days. I might be cutting it close on my shared hosting plan lol. Would you guys be able to offer some suggestions as to how i might be able to find how how the margin-top is added to the video element?

Comment: Hey Lukecom thanks for the reply! I think Mike Jona's suggestion might have fixed it. could you confirm if the video's displaying properly?

Comment: Since this question was reliant on users looking at an external site link (now edited out) I think it can be closed as "not self contained".

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'volume' of null
```

Because on line 385 you're trying to set the volume of an element 'jazz_player' that you haven't created in the HTML.

If you want to override any CSS settings that are being set in the JS of a plugin, you can use `!important`, eg:

```
.my-overriding-class{
   margin-top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Nick Jonas! I could kiss you right now! It seem to work on my end!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick tip btw.
1349 may be as wide as your screen is, but some screens may be bigger and smaller. HTML5 video is nice, as it kinda adjusts the video based on the frame.
Here's the actual answer: Replace 1349px with 100%. Also add in width, and make it 100%. Than, removed margin-top and margin-left with margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px. Final code:
      element.style {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; }

On mobile devices, with different screen sizes, I would make it so that the video doesnt show btw.

This looks right, but someone correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Isn't `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;` the same as `margin: 0`?

Comment: Umm...maybe? I forget if you can do that, I thought if you only did the first one, it only applied to the top. I may be wrong.

Comment: It sounds like he's using a plugin, where the JS is setting the width manually by browser width/height in pixels.  So he can either dig into the source code and fix it, or override the CSS in his own stylesheet by using `!important`.  And yes, it should be margin: 0.

Comment: Yeah I think a plugin us auto adjusting the size based on the screen. Would you guys be able to check to see if the video is loading properly?